# python with open for loop

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, file-io

I have a decent sized web scraping script that has an input of 25K+ urls into an individual page scraping function that runs a for loop through all of the urls.  At the end of the for loop it writes the results to a csv.
Currently, I have this code in place:

```
if link == url[0]:
        # Creating the file and writing headers with the first entry and closing after
        # the first entry to go from write mode to append mode
        with open(file_Name, 'w') as f:
            stats_df.to_csv(f)
            record_Counter = record_Counter + 1
            print ('Two entries for one game recorded.  Counter = '  + str(record_Counter))
    elif link == url[1]:
        # Opening the file in append mode and keeping it open for the majority of the loop
        # and writing with no headers
        f = open(file_Name, mode = 'a') 
        stats_df.to_csv(f, header=False)
        record_Counter = record_Counter + 1
        print ('Two entries for one game recorded.  Counter = '  + str(record_Counter))
    elif link == url[-1]:
        # Writing the final entry of this page and closing the file
        stats_df.to_csv(f, header=False)
        record_Counter = record_Counter + 1
        print ('Two entries for one game recorded.  Counter = '  + str(record_Counter))
        f.close()
    else:
        # Writing all entries in between
        stats_df.to_csv(f, header=False)
        record_Counter = record_Counter + 1
        print ('Two entries for one game recorded.  Counter = '  + str(record_Counter))
```

Previously, I had this:

```
if link == url[0]:
        with open(file_Name, 'w') as f:
            stats_df.to_csv(f)
            record_Counter = record_Counter + 1
            print ('Two entries for one game recorded.  Counter = '  + str(record_Counter))
else:
        with open(file_Name, 'a') as f:
            stats_df.to_csv(f)
            record_Counter = record_Counter + 1
            print ('Two entries for one game recorded.  Counter = '  + str(record_Counter))
```

My concern with the simpler code was that I was opening and closing the csv file 25K times and it was slowing down my run time.  My current concern is the problem with memory corruption on an exception with leaving f open.

Am I justified in either of my concerns?  Thanks for your time.

Comment: code is corrupt (idenntation) - thats the case in your sources?

Comment: I would go for the 2nd aproach, getting partial results seems to be better then getting whatever you have with the 1st one. Restarting the scraping is easier as well - just restart with the n-th entry from your 25k urls.

Comment: Just from pure interest -. I see several web-scraping python threads each day and I always aks myself: "Why"?

Comment: Patrick:  No, the code works in my actual code and is currently running.  I probably made some formatting errors when putting it into SO formatting for code blocks.

Comment: "opening and closing the csv file 25K times" seems pretty trivial... have you actually benchmarked this to see if it is any sort of bottleneck? I would go with the second form, and if your code is working too slow, then *profile* it to figure out if the above is actually a concern. This smacks of pre-mature optimization.

Comment: @PatrickArtner it's the wild-west with regards to data right now. Everyone wants some, and scraping the web is a good way of getting it. Python provides several libraries that make web-scraping easy for beginners, and I'd imagine that's why you see the topic so often on the python tag. I see you are in Deutschland. My impression is that Germany (and the EU in general) has much stricter control over hoarding data. In the USA, outside of special cases (e.g. medical information), it is essentially unregulated.

Answer (score 1):

> The real problem is that programmers have spent far too much time worrying about efficiency in the wrong places and at the wrong times; premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming.--Donald Knuth

I started learning to program in...1982 or 83 on a time sharing mini computer. Stuff ran **SLOWLY**. Memory was tight. As a consequence I worry way too much about how much memory/ops/etc. my code uses. Letting go of this is hard.

You say:

> My concern with the simpler code was that I was opening and closing the csv file 25K times and it was slowing down my run time.

Of course it was. But noticeably? How time sensitive is the application? If it takes an extra 60 seconds to run, what is the impact?

On the other hand:

> My current concern is the problem with memory corruption on an exception with leaving f open.

What do you mean by this?

If you hit an exception and the program shuts down Python will clean up after itself. It might not scrub every bit of memory on the way out if you're worried about someone doing something nefarious, but the whole point of exception handling is to handle exceptions in a safe and consistent way.

I could be very wrong about this, but the way I read this code:

```
elif link == url[1]:
    # Opening the file in append mode and keeping it open for the majority of the loop
    # and writing with no headers
    f = open(file_Name, mode = 'a') 
    stats_df.to_csv(f, header=False)
    record_Counter = record_Counter + 1
    print ('Two entries for one game recorded.  Counter = '  + str(record_Counter))
```

You're *attempting* to open file_name every time through the loop and call the file handle f. I don't know what happens inside the VM with this, but either (a) you're closing and reopening the file every time, or (ii) you're finding the file already open and just reusing f. I don't know how much more efficient this is than just opening the file in append and blasting data to it.

IMO I don't think the difference in speed is worth it at that scale.

On the other hand Knuth also said:

> Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%.

Comment: I always upvote the wisdom of Knuth. I started programming only a maybe 3 years ago and I still find myself obsessing over trivial aspects of my code. Things like striving to do everything in a single pass over a data-structure, when simply doing two passes would make the code 10x more readable and straightforward, with negligible effects on runtime.